# my issue is messagpopbox of login is getting called asap i open the frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

```py
  for F in (StartPage,LoginPage,LoginPageAdmin,Validate,Page1,Page2,Page3): 

                        frame = F(container, self)

                        # initializing frame of that object from 
                        # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with 
                        # for loop 
                        self.frames[F] = frame

                        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")


class Validate(tk.Frame): 
        def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
                tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            
                username_verify = StringVar()
                password_verify = StringVar()
              
                username = "AJF" #that's the given username
                password = "123" #that's the given password
                username1 = username_verify.get()
                password1 = password_verify.get()
                    
                if username == username1 and password == password1:
                        messagebox.showinfo("info","success") 
                else:
                        messagebox.showerror("info","Failed") 
                 
                button1 = tk.Button(self, text ="page1", 
                        command = lambda : controller.show_frame(Page1)) 
        
                # putting the button in its place by 
                # using grid 
                button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 200)
                button1.place(x=130, y=130)
```

[image]

Comment: format the code properly and explain your problem in the body, not in the title.

Comment: You're using `if` in the `__init__()` which means, it will get called when the class gets initialized. You have to move the `if` inside of a function that gets called, when you press button or triggered by some event.

Comment: Your code is clearly creating the frames upon initialization, and in that initialization you are clearly checking the user input before the user has a chance to input anything.